# Pyspark: how to make a query that returns only IDs with entries greater than one?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that looks like the following

```
Timestamp,  Name,    Value  
1577862435, Tom,      0.25  
1577915618, Tom,      0.50  
1577839734, John,     0.34
1577839734, John,     0.34
1577839734, John,     0.34
1577839734, Eric,     0.34
```

To count the entries for each user, I do

```
query = """ SELECT ID,
            COUNT(*) AS `num`
            FROM
            myTable
            GROUP BY Name
            ORDER BY num DESC
"""
count = spark.sql(query)
count.show()

Name    num
John     3
Tom      2
Eric     1
```

I would a query that renturns IDs that have `num>=2`. My final table should be:

```
Timestamp,  Name,    Value  
1577862435, Tom,      0.25  
1577915618, Tom,      0.50  
1577839734, John,     0.34
1577839734, John,     0.34
1577839734, John,     0.34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this as SQL:

```
SELECT ID, Name, num
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) AS num
      FROM myTable t
     ) t
WHERE num >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use window functions then.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window 

df = spark.table("myTable")

df.withColumn(
    "cnt", 
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy("Name"))
).where("cnt > 1").drop("cnt").show()
```